# When connecting Microsoft Access to a MySql database using ODBC connections, every query ran takes forever and shows up in the slow query log

Tags: mysql, performance, odbc

When connecting Microsoft Access to a MySql database using ODBC connections, every query ran takes forever and shows up in the slow query log.

I just got a new job at a small company, their entire system is based around Microsoft Access and MySql, and it's so flapping slow.

My job is to create a replacement, but I want to speed up the current system in the meantime, any suggestions?

Cheers Guys

Comment: Just to clarify, I cleared all of the logs yesterday and let everything coninue as normal. This morning when I checked MySql Administrator, the 'General Query Log' was blank, the 'Slow Query Log' was full!

Answer (score 0):

Try using "EXPLAIN" to look at how efficient the queries are.  It is possible that they aren't using indexes.

It is also possible that you need to increase the size of your  key_buffer_size (in mysql.ini). MySQL loves a large key cache!